# NameError: name 'get' is not defined (still issues)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

EDIT: Still getting the error (the script executed once but the output was blank)

I get the following error when trying to run this script [python scraping](https://gist.github.com/isabellabenabaye/960b255705843485698875dc193e477e) from the CMD:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Far\Desktop\Coding>python scraping_imdb_episodes.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Far\Desktop\Coding\scraping_imdb_episodes.py", line 7, in <module>
    response = get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1439629/episodes?season=' + str(sn))
NameError: name 'get' is not defined
```

I searched for the solution [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/genindex-G.html) but don't grasp what's going wrong.

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
# Initializing the series that the loop will populate
community_episodes = []

# For every season in the series-- range depends on the show
for sn in range(1,7):
    # Request from the server the content of the web page by using get(), and store the server’s response in the variable response
    response = get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1439629/episodes?season=' + str(sn))

    # Parse the content of the request with BeautifulSoup
    page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Select all the episode containers from the season's page
    episode_containers = page_html.find_all('div', class_ = 'info')

    # For each episode in each season
    for episodes in episode_containers:
            # Get the info of each episode on the page
            season = sn
            episode_number = episodes.meta['content']
            title = episodes.a['title']
            airdate = episodes.find('div', class_='airdate').text.strip()
            rating = episodes.find('span', class_='ipl-rating-star__rating').text
            total_votes = episodes.find('span', class_='ipl-rating-star__total-votes').text
            desc = episodes.find('div', class_='item_description').text.strip()
            # Compiling the episode info
            episode_data = [season, episode_number, title, airdate, rating, total_votes, desc]

            # Append the episode info to the complete dataset
            community_episodes.append(episode_data)
```

I just tested `get` and `request.get` on this [Online Compiler](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/) and still got the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
NameError: name 'get' is not defined
```

[image: get error]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
```

[image: requests error]

Comment: you have to use do `response = requests.get(url)`

Comment: Please include a [mre] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: The snippet says ***"partial code"*** at the top. How exactly to fetch the contents of the URL is sort of omitted here, i.e. it's "bring your own `get`". The rest of the code is supposed to illustrate what to do with the content once you've fetched it.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I just installed requests and now it's running ok. Didn't know we needed it.

Comment: @khelwood thanks for the suggestion. The example was given in the 1st link https://gist.github.com/isabellabenabaye/960b255705843485698875dc193e477e .

Comment: @Lod A link is not a [mre]. Code required to understand your problem should be included in your question.

Comment: @khelwood ok. Do you mean pasting the code from the link as valid minimal reproducible example? plus the error code? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the mre should be included in a code block in your question, and error messages or output should be included in your question.

Comment: If you want to use `requests.get`, then you need `import requests`. If you want to use just `get` then you need `from requests import get`.

Comment: @khelwood thanks. Here I got both `requests.get` with `import requests` https://i.imgur.com/spfYXWl.png  and `get`  with `from requests import get` https://i.imgur.com/7WI4auB.png  but the errors remain. What am I not doing right? Thanks.

Comment: You need to `import requests` **in your .py file**, not just type it into a console and then run the file separately.

Comment: @deceze thanks a lot for the pointer! I didn't know about that. I added `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`  and `import requests` as first 2 lines of the py script and now  I'm not getting any more errors. Thanks again. Be well!

Comment: @deceze I got it sorted finally here: https://pastebin.com/fCh3sGPK Many thanks again guys.

Comment: [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code and errors.

Comment: @outis thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @outis yes it's a similar solution thanks. I did end up solving it by putting `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and `import requests` at the top of the script as @deceze pointed me to in previous comment. Be well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"get" is a method from requests library. Make sure that you have imported get from requests or else use

```
response = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1439629/episodes?season=' + str(sn))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @faheem Sharif. I just installed requests and now it's running ok. Didn't know we needed it.

Comment: I just add the final code link here (shared in previous comment) so others can find it quickly for reference: https://pastebin.com/fCh3sGPK Many thanks again!